# coding a response to a HTTP GET command in C

Tags: c

i'd prefer psuedo code or a logical breakdown of it so that i can write my own code for it myself and learn from it.
i already have functions for checking local resources (homepage.html for example) and loading a config file that sets variables.

i now need to write a function that

> Receives a URI (ie:www.microsoft.com/windows/mypage.html) would be broken up into DOMAIN: www.microsoft.com GET /windows/mypage.html
>
> Would read it in as 2 arguments( not sure?)
>
> -domain is set in config file not part of input

`>GET` is passed as an argument

`>/windows/mypage.html` file or file path is specified

From my understanding i need to do the following...

- main function is set with argc and *argv[]
- if argument (ie. "GET") = GET then pass second argument (file path)
- once argument is passed then open specified file
- if no file is specified and only 1 argument is passed (ie. GET) load a default file that is specified in configuration.

I think i'm on the right track, but any input would be appreciated.

my question is, am i correct in my logic above?

thanks

Comment: It sounds both as if you're trying to write a web server, and as you're trying to write a script executed *by* a web server. Quite confusing, please clarify.

Comment: i'm trying to write a script that takes an input of `GET /filename.html` so yes it is a web server i suppose. but currently as it stands as if i'm already connected to it and on the command line... so i issue GET and a filename and it will load them... hope that makes sense @unwind